# How can I get "XX% of users liked this movie" data from Google via API?

Tags: google-api

Basically exactly what the title says, does anyone know of an API that I can access the data that displays on an organic Google search about a movie...i.e. if you Google "The Lion King", you see that "87% liked this movie" in the results.